Is there a security vulnerability in Advanced Custom Fields related to the SCF fork?
I don't wish to get into the politics going on between WP Engine and Wordpress.org (and I understand there are strong undercurrents to the ACF issue) but in his post Secure Custom Fields Matt Mullenweg states among other things "SCF has been updated to remove commercial upsells and fix a security problem".
I have not been able to find any other references to a security issue with ACF – does anyone know if there is any kind of vulnerability in ACF or if "security problem" here means something more general?
In other words, is there a security issue I need to jump on now or can we wait for the dust to settle before choosing a direction?

It's probably the issue mentioned in the changelog for 6.3.8 here. The developers were unable to release the patch on dot org themselves because Mullenweg had unilaterally revoked their access to the plugin repository because the plugin is owned by WP Engine. The issue has been patched in the version available directly from the developer, as you can see from the changelog.
The security issue used to justify the takeover of the plugin page only existed at that time because the developers were prevented from patching it themselves by the person who took it over. You can draw your own conclusions about what's going on there.

In the end the fork is a "political" move, not a technical one. If wp.org would have forked every plugin which has a security issue that the developer was not able to fix in a week, wp.org would have had to maintain most plugins in the repository.
So while jacob is right, the fork should be treated as what it is - a tantrum, and judged based on that as long as there is no other evidance to the contrary. Matt needs to show he is actually going to invest the effort in maintaining the fork before I would use it for anything.
All that said, the question is in so many ways out of scope here.

nothing like a downvote which do not bother to say which the 3 parts of the answer it refers to. was it you matt ;)?

Sorry, it was I that downvoted this because your answer focusses heavily on the politics - when my question specifically started with "I don't wish to get into the politics" - while not addressing the question I asked which was "is there any kind of vulnerability in ACF".    In other words I don't see this as being an answer to my question.

the point of this site is to create a knowledge base that all people can learn from, not to be an unpaid support channels to solve some specific problem of a specific user in a way (s)he desires. But you are not the first to think like that

as a minnow on this particular stack (but with decent rep on some other stacks) I understand and agree with your comment above - save for your specious assertion as to how/what I think, and, it appears, very different interpretations of the question I asked.

your question asked for not refering to the political situation, which I didn't actually do, I just acknowledged it is such a situation, and explained why just a fork which is not promissed to be maintained should not be touched regardless of the reasons the fork happened
